# What is/are the antecedent(s) of the relative pronoun "who" in the following sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning, relative-pronouns, reference, antecedents

In the following sentence, what is/are the antecedent(s) of the relative pronoun "who"?

> Children include all biological children, legally adopted children, and stepchildren **who** are unmarried and under the age of 21 on the date you submit your entry.

Is the antecedent of the relative pronoun "who", only the *stepchildren* or does "who" refer to *all biological children, legally adopted children, and stepchildren*?

In other words, do biological children need to be under the age of 21 to be considered children in this sentence?

Comment: Common sense suggests yes, but the sentence is ambiguous. A comma after _stepchildren_ would help.

Comment: @KateBunting +1 and you're right otherwise, but a comma after "stepchildren" would make "*who...*" a non-defining relative clause, meaning that *all stepchildren are by definition unmarried and under 21*!